# Calendar dates dropdown list using Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, calendar

I am trying to create a calendar by using Javascript where dates will be shown as a list. It is easy to access from mobile device. Now calendar is showing as a box format. Like dates will be:-

```
    1
    2
    3 and so on
```

instead

```
    1 2 3 4 and so on
```

Please check the codepen link :- http://codepen.io/whusterj/pen/vmJda

Comment: You should post a [**minimal**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code here. Links to other sites are unreliable and if they become broken, the question becomes useless for future reference.

Comment: The code is huge, so I could not. Okay, wait, I am putting some important code here. If you can please take a look once from the link. Thanks.